# PHP Form Update SQL Database

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update the database on submit but none of the fields data is been added to the database, I've attached my snippet below. Any advice would be great.

$sql="INSERT INTO `members` SET `First Name` = '".$first_name."', `Last Name` = '".$last_name."', `D.O.B` = '".$date_of_birth."', `EmailAddress` = '".$email."', `Favourite` = '".$favouritebarrio."', `Company Name` = '".$company_name."' WHERE `Activation` = '".$activation_codeurl."';

Comment: Did you do <form method="POST"?

Comment: You need to debug first by using echo statements.

Comment: Only error I'm getting is
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `Activation` = 'ad3cd3c1'' at line 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close **" "**

WHERE Activation = '".$activation_codeurl."'**"**;

Comment: Litterally just seen this before you commented,
$sql="UPDATE `members` SET `First Name` = '".$first_name."', `Last Name` = '".$last_name."', `D.O.B` = '".$date_of_birth."', `EmailAddress` = '".$email."', `Favourite` = '".$favouritebarrio."', `Company Name` = '".$company_name."' WHERE `Activation` = '".$activation_codeurl."'; 

Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE members SET First Name = '$first_name', Last Name = '$last_name', D.O.B. = '$date_of_birth', EmailAddress = '$email', Favourite = '$favouritebarrio', Company Name= '$company_name WHERE Activation = '$activation_codeurl'";
```